# Fetch committed versions of ALL FILES from GIT

Tags: git, extract, fetch

I am new to GIT.  How to fetch 'committed versions' of ALL FILES from 'GIT repo' ?

For Example, I have three files in GIT

```
one.c  v1.3 (v1.3 is tag and committed)
one.c  v1.2
one.c  v1.1

two.c  v1.2 (committed)
two.c  v1.1

three.c  v1.1 (committed)
```

How to fetch one.c (v1.3), two.c (v1.2) and three.c (v1.1) from GIT ?

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Comment: Huh? [`git pull origin master`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)?

Comment: What do you mean by committed versions? Versions are created only after you commit them.

Comment: Yes that was a typo reg 'committed versions'

Comment: The git core actually doesn't care much about files. When you fetch a version or in git language, a commit, it is always the whole bundle of files that build one version.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `git pull`, your working directory is populated with the latest versions of all files.

Comment: How can I use 'git fetch' to extract 'files based on tags' ?  Can I create a new branch while I do 'git fetch' ?

Comment: To grab all the files based on a tag, do `git checkout <tagname>`. To create a branch, do `git branch <branchname>`. I would highly recommend you give the Git book a read at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. Using Git will be much more enjoyable when you have learned the fundamentals. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you dave,  I'll go through it